# codeigniter issue with loading view from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter and really interested in trying it out. I followed the guide but ran into a problem. It seems like I am unable to load my first page properly.

I have inside the view folder another folder called general and inside it index.php.

in controller folder, I have sub-folder with general and inside it is Default controller.

I have the following route and yet the page showing is blank

```
$route['default_controller'] = "general/default";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

When I visit the link, I type this in browser:

```
http://localhost:8888/treventa/
```

and the screen is blank. Am I doing something wrong? Sorry if this is too simple but a person got to learn from his mistake :)

Comment: The `default_controller` must be like `folderName/file`.

Comment: I changed it to $route['general/default'] = "/"; and still didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with me step by step:**

- Firstly: **the Controller**:

[image]

**(main.php) File content**

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('general/welcome');
    }
}
```

- Secondly: **The view**:

[image]

**(welcome.php) File content**
You can put anything you want

```
<h1> Hello, I'm the view file  </h1>
```

- Finaly: **The routes**:

[image]

**(routes.php) File content**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "general/main";
```

Now call the script like this `http://localhost/codeIgniter/`, that's where `codeIgniter` is the script folder name.

I think everything now is clear.

Answer (score 0):

`CI` trying to use method `default()` of `general` controller. If You want to use folders for controllers, make sure You specify method, so try `$route['default_controller'] = "general/default/index";`

And one more thing: this method (`default_controller`) will be used when You trying reach Your root `http://localhost:8888/`, if You want to route request from `http://localhost:8888/treventa/` to default controller, You need to add route-rule to `/config/routes.php` something like `$route['treventa'] = "general/main/index";`